# R Plotly Two Plots side by side

Tags: r, plot, plotly

I'm trying to get two donut plots side by side in plotly. However, I'm only getting one image. Any advice on what I'm missing?

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = c("a","b", "c", 34,28, 29), nrow = 3, ncol = 2))
colnames(df1) <- c("category", "count")
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = c("Q","F", "G", 29,50, 76), nrow = 3, ncol = 2))
colnames(df2) <- c("group", "count")


p <- subplot(
  plot_ly(df1, labels = category, values = count, type = "pie", hole = 0.6, showlegend = TRUE),
  plot_ly(df2, labels = group, values = count, type = "pie", hole = 0.6, showlegend = TRUE),
  margin = 0.05,
  nrows = 2
)
p
```

Current Output:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're so close. This is an adaptation of your code to [Plotly's pie charts examples](https://plot.ly/r/pie-charts/):

```
plot_ly(df1, labels = category, values = count, type = "pie", hole = 0.6, showlegend = TRUE,
        domain = list(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0.5, 1))) %>%
  add_trace(data = df2, labels = group, values = count, type = "pie", hole = 0.6, showlegend = TRUE,
            domain = list(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 0.5)))
```

[image: side-by-side pies]

(They are using `add_trace` instead of a parent `subplot`.)

If you want to add gridlines (per @Technophobe01's example), you would add

```
ax <- list(showline= TRUE)
plot_ly(...) %>% add_trace(...) %.%
  layout(xaxis = ax, yaxis = ax)
```

Many more options for it, sapmles on their [axes](https://plot.ly/r/axes/) page.

Comment: Using `domain` like that reminds of me using `par(fig=..., new=TRUE)` in base R. Seems a bit draconian, but it works.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this. Why doesn't subplot work? The docs suggest that?

Comment: No idea, sorry. (Can you "accept" one of the answers?)

Answer (score 1):

If you take `r2evans` solution you can match it to your question as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = c("a","b", "c", 34,28, 29), nrow = 3, ncol = 2))
colnames(df1) <- c("category", "count")
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = c("Q","F", "G", 29,50, 76), nrow = 3, ncol = 2))
colnames(df2) <- c("group", "count")


p2<- subplot(
  plot_ly(df1, labels = category, values = count, type = "pie", hole = 0.6, showlegend = TRUE,
          domain = list(x = c(0, 0.5), y = c(0, 1))), 
  add_trace(data = df2, labels = group, values = count, type = "pie", hole = 0.6,
              domain = list(x = c(0.5, 1), y = c(0, 1))),
  margin = 0.05) 
p2
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Is it `subplot` that's adding the background grid? I couldn't get it to work without it. (BTW: I missed `nrows = 2`, and you followed suit ... :-)

Comment: Yes, as coded the subplot is adding the background grid. ref: https://plot.ly/r/subplots/

Comment: Can be done with [`layout`](https://plot.ly/r/axes/), though in this context I'm not certain it adds much (what does `0,0` mean when slightly outside of a pie chart?).

Comment: r2evans - Mia culpa maxima - fixed the nrows=2 issue:-)